# How to Convert Map's Iterator from Java to Scala using JavaConversions

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-java-interop

I use Scala 2.10.3.
I have `result.iterator()` returning `Iterator<java.util.Map<String, Object>>`. (in Java so)

I want to convert it to the Scala equivalent.
I use `import scala.collection.JavaConversions._` to try to do the trick.

However it seems that it is unable to take into account type parameters, in this case, it can convert `java.util.Iterator` to the Scala equivalent, but fails to convert `java.util.Map` in the Scala equivalent.

Indeed, a compiler error occurs at this line:

```
val results: Iterator[Map[String, AnyRef]] = result.iterator()

    type mismatch;
     found   : java.util.Iterator[java.util.Map[String,Object]]
     required: scala.collection.Iterator[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,AnyRef]]
     val results: Iterator[Map[String, AnyRef]] = result.iterator()
                                                                ^
```

Is there a short way to do the trick?

Comment: `JavaConversions` is deprecated, you should favour `JavaConverters` as suggested by @senia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could explicitly specify what you want to convert using `JavaConverters` instead of `JavaConversions` like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
def javaIt: java.util.Iterator[java.util.Map[String, Object]] = ???

def scalaIt = javaIt.asScala map {_.asScala}
// Iterator[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Object]]
```

Comment: @Kevin Wright Yes of course, but it takes at least 3 minutes to validate an answer. (stackoverflow prevents otherwise)